# List Array Shuffle or bang my head against the wall?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I am trying to shuffle a list of number from 1-15. then take the first 5 number and assign index 1 to the text of the first btn 2nd number to the text of the 2nd btn etc.... The trouble is I have tried almost every thing I have read here in Stackoverflow but nothing has helped. Please help.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnClickListener,  
CountdownTimerFinishedListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
//SET UP SPINS

 private TextView spins;    
 private Button spin;
 private Button s_1;
 private Button s_2;
 private Button s_3;
 private Button s_4;
 private Button s_5;

  private static final Random rand = new Random();

int totalspins = 15;
int gamescore = 0;
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;
int s3 = 0;
int s4 = 0;
int s5 = 0;
int[] b_list ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15};

     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_layout);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    gamescore=(0);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setText(String.valueOf("SCORE: "+ gamescore));
    totalspins = (15);
    spins = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spins);
    spins.setText(String.valueOf("SPINS: "+ totalspins));
    spin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spin);
    s_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spin_1);
    s_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spin_2);
    s_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spin_3);
    s_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spin_4);
    s_5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spin_5);
    b_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    b_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
    b_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
    b_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_4);
    b_5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_5);

    //int randIntb1 = rand.nextInt(15)+1;
     b_1.setText(String.valueOf(b_list[0]));//randIntb1
    //int randIntb2 = rand.nextInt(15)+1;
    b_2.setText(String.valueOf(b_list[1]));//randIntb2
    //int randIntb3 = rand.nextInt(15)+1;
    b_3.setText(String.valueOf(b_list[2]));//randIntb3
    //int randIntb4 = rand.nextInt(15)+1;
    b_4.setText(String.valueOf(b_list[3]));//randIntb4
    //int randIntb5 = rand.nextInt(15)+1;
    b_5.setText(String.valueOf(b_list[4]));//randIntb5

     spin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private Object Button;
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //spin.setEnabled(false);
            int randInts1 = rand.nextInt(17)+1;
            s_1.setText(String.valueOf(randInts1));
            s1=(randInts1);
            int randInts2 = rand.nextInt(17)+15;
            s_2.setText(String.valueOf(randInts2));
            s2=(randInts2);
            int randInts3 = rand.nextInt(17)+30;
            s_3.setText(String.valueOf(randInts3));
            s3=(randInts3);
            int randInts4 = rand.nextInt(17)+45;
            s_4.setText(String.valueOf(randInts4));
            s4=(randInts4);
            int randInts5 = rand.nextInt(17)+60;
            s_5.setText(String.valueOf(randInts5));
            s5=(randInts5);


            totalspins = (totalspins - 1);
            spins.setText(String.valueOf("SPINS: "+ totalspins));
            if(totalspins <= 0){
                totalspins =(15);
            }
            }

    });






    b_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private Object Button;
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (b_1.getText() == (s_1.getText())){
                gamescore =(gamescore + s1);
                score.setText(String.valueOf("SCORE: "+ gamescore));
                b_1.setText(String.valueOf(""));
                s_1.setText(String.valueOf(""));
                }
            }
    });
    b_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private Object Button;
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (b_2.getText() == (s_1.getText())){
                gamescore =(gamescore + s1);
                score.setText(String.valueOf("SCORE: "+ gamescore));
                b_2.setText(String.valueOf(""));
                s_1.setText(String.valueOf(""));
                }
            }
    });
    b_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private Object Button;
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (b_3.getText() == (s_1.getText())){
                gamescore =(gamescore + s1);
                score.setText(String.valueOf("SCORE: "+ gamescore));
                b_3.setText(String.valueOf(""));
                s_1.setText(String.valueOf(""));
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with the button logic? The shuffling? What have you tried?

Comment: Please show us your code.  SO ethos is to help people solve their own problems (and learn to do it) ... rather than to provide potted solutions for (simple) problems.

Comment: You should definitely post some of your attempts here.  I think you'll find that folks are more apt to assist if they see that you're giving it "the old college try" first.

Comment: Uh... how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: This isn't very clear.  If you're just trying to randomly permute an array, Google for that: random array permutation.  It's 2 lines of code.

Comment: Mistakenly added my comment as answer. As others have said, what progress have you made so far, and where are you getting stuck specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shuffling a list is pretty easy:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>()
for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}

Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

Then, when you want to make them the text of the buttons just do:

```
b_1.setText(numbers.get(0).toString());
b_2.setText(numbers.get(1).toString());
b_3.setText(numbers.get(2).toString());
b_4.setText(numbers.get(3).toString());
b_5.setText(numbers.get(4).toString());
```

However, keeping these buttons in some sort of data structure would probably be better:

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
//Fill list to your heart's content

Collections.shuffle(numbers);
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length() && i < numbers.length(); i++) {
    buttons.get(i).setText(numbers.get(i).toString());
}
```

*Edited for me forgetting that Java lists use get() and not at() like C++ vectors*

Comment: Collin I have tried that in as many forms as I could figure out being new to java. it warned me about integer. My memory has gone from hitting my head on the wall.

Comment: Warned you about Integer? What was the warning? I didn't compile this, so I could have messed something up.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen this. thanks I will try it. I am sure this will work

Comment: You are right, the .at gave a warning. Thanks again. I checked your answer.

Comment: Why did my question get a -1 was it that bad of question?

Comment: I think you don't deserve that. +1 from me. :)

Comment: Quoi, Thanks for the +1 I had researched the question for 3 days before asking. the part I was missing was : b_1.setText(numbers.get(0).toString());